# Xorg error coming from running xpra

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xorg, xpra

I am trying to follow this [Youtube guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ukqs5M5Fthg) and run X applications in a browser. However I got a few errors and I fixed them and now it's down to one. Which is

```
xpra start --bind-tcp=0.0.0.0:9876 --html=on --start-child=xterm
```

and I get

```
Warning: cannot use the system proxy for 'start' subcommand,
 failed to connect to '/run/xpra/system':
 [Errno 2] No such file or directory
(base) ok@ok:~$ Entering daemon mode; any further errors will be reported to:
  /run/user/1003/xpra/S26428.log
```

So I open the log as suggested and I see

```
(EE)
Fatal server error:
(EE)
Invalid argument -logfile with elevated privileges
(EE)
(EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.
(EE)
InitException: Xorg did not provide a display number using -displayfd
xpra initialization error:
 Xorg did not provide a display number using -displayfd
2020-01-16 14:40:56,098 closing TCP socket 0.0.0.0:9876^[[0m
```

which seems to suggest the issue is with X not xpra. But I can't seem to find any info on how to fix this. I found [this](https://www.xpra.org/trac/ticket/1777) which suggests I should install dummy driver with

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-dummy
```

which I did, and the rest of intructions does not make much sense to me.

I am running Ubuntu 18.04. Can anyone suggest a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

> Warning: cannot use the system proxy for 'start' subcommand,

This is covered in the [xpra FAQ](https://xpra.org/trac/wiki/FAQ), this is harmless and you can ignore it.

> which seems to suggest the issue is with X not xpra.

Correct.
Xpra is trying to start a virtual framebuffer to run your applications, and for some strange reason, it is failing.

Two things you can try:

- use the official [xpra.org packages](https://xpra.org/trac/wiki/Download), as the downstream Ubuntu ones are known to be badly broken
- use Xvfb instead of Xdummy, edit `/etc/xpra/conf.d/55_server_x11.conf` uncomment it and comment out the current one

Comment: How do I use the official xpra.org packages. Total Linux noob here. Is there a command I can run?

Comment: The second suggestion also doesn't make sense to me. You mean i comment some lines in that file?? I see a comment saying required on Ubuntu where Xorg is broken.

Comment: @xiaodai the download link I posted has: "For step by step instructions on setting up these repositories, follow.."

Comment: as for using Xvfb: there are two commented out (starting with "#") examples of "xvfb=" options in that file, plus the one actually used (not commented out). Use the one that looks like "xvfb=Xvfb ...."